How to convert OData filter query to class FilterValue
Please help me. I want get data from one service and filter and paging by odata query.
Example:
var data = _service.Get("(contains(Name,'join') and (Age eq 18 and Gender eq 0))");

I'm working on a job that needs to convert from OData filter string to FilterValue.
This is the structure FilterValue:
public class FilterValue
 {
     public FilterValue()
     {
     }

     public FilterValue(string value)
     {
         Value = value;
     }

     public FilterValue? Left { get; set; }
     public FilterValue? Right { get; set; }
     public string? Value { get; set; }
     public string? LogicalOperator { get; set; }
}

Can someone help me handle the transformation from string OData filter to a FilterValue object? Thanks.
Example:
OData filter:
(contains(Name,'join') and (Age eq 18 and Gender eq 0))

Target:
{
    Left: {
        Left {
            Value: "Name",
        },
        LogicalOperator: "contains",
        Right: {
            Value: "join"
        }
    },
    LogicalOperator: "and",
    Right: {
        Left: {
            Left: {
                Value: "Age"
            },
            LogicalOperator: "eq",
            Right: {
                Value: "18"
            }
        },
        LogicalOperator: "and",
        Right:  {
            Left: {
                Value: "Gender"
            },
            LogicalOperator: "eq",
            Right: {
                Value: "0"
            }
        }
    }
}


Does this answer your question? How to Parse OData $filter in C#

I will try it, thank you for the suggestion
